# Adding objects to users in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-users

I am very new to Django and I am trying to build a web app that users can add the books they read and see other users that read the same book. How can I do this in Django? What functions should I add?

Comment: Your question is very broad. I suggest looking into some tutorials. You can have a look into this YouTube channel.
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRM1gWNTDx0SHIqUJygD-kQ

There are many practical lessons there. For instance this video will help you work with the built in Django user model:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QS9z4g0JAOY

You can code along after you find your use case.

And I strongly advise you to take some full featured courses on Django first.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that.